# call a method using string in Java

Tags: java

How can I call a method using String in Java. For example,

```
    String a = "call";
    int b = a();

    private static int call() {
         return 1;
    }
```

I know that it's got something to do with reflection, but I am not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: That's an invalid statement in Java

Comment: Don’t you think it’s more easy to have a method that receives a String and using a switch case call a specific method?

Comment: You have to use Reflection.

Comment: user7 i know its invalid, that's why I am asking if there is a way

Comment: See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string). There are lots of examples of reflection in SO.

Comment: Here's documentation on how to do this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: There is a way, reflection, but in 99% of the cases, there is a much better, safer, faster way of solving the problem. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do this with *reflection*. First get a reference to the `Class`, use that to obtain the `Method` by-name. Then you can invoke that method. For example,

```
public class Test {    
    public static int call() {
        return 42;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method m = Test.class.getMethod("call", new Class[0]);
        Object o = m.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Outputs the meaning of life, the universe and everything.

Comment: **The meaning of life**? (I'm gonna try this thing. Maybe I can solve that String Theory thingy).

Comment: @DevilsHnd [The old](https://youtu.be/5ZLtcTZP2js) and [the modern](https://youtu.be/aboZctrHfK8).

Answer (score 0):

Reflection. Or Method Handles.

Reflection:

```
 import java.lang.Reflect;

 public class SomeClass {
     public void someMethod() {
         String a = "call";

         try {
             Method m = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(a);
             m.setAccessible(true);
             m.invoke(null);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
    }
}
```

Without Reflection, using MethodHandles:

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "call";
        try {
            MethodHandle h = MethodHandles.lookup()
                .findStatic(Example.class, a, MethodType.methodType(Integer.TYPE));
            int result = (int) h.invokeExact();
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static int call() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

MethodHandles are said to be faster, but they have some additional limitations, like you can only use them to call code that you can call in the current context.

This limitation works for us in this case, because `call` is private, so we can call it. But if we try to do that from a different class, we will get an exception. (We can pass the result of `lookup()` or `findStatic()`, and others can call it for us.)

Also, the MethodHandles example works if there is a `SecurityManager`.